# Adobe cq5- getting started

Tags: adobe, aem

I have started learning Adobe CQ5 recently. I am having difficult time in understanding the content model in CQ5, like how the hierarchy between content is stored?
The tutorials on adobe site is directly jumping into the implementation, is there a site where i can read/use to learn cq5 step-by-step?

Note - i checked the other thread, it talks more about procurring a installable for development purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe AEM (aka CQ5) is based upon [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org/),which uses JCR for storing its content (implemented by Jackrabbit/CRX), I recommend you to start learning a bit about Sling, then you can jump into CQ5. You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018266/what-is-the-purpose-behind-building-of-apache-sling-felix-jackrabbit-projects/17025918#17025918) that talks about Sling and JCR.

When you are done, check the [CQ5 development guide](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/v5_1/html-resources/cq5_guide_developer/cq5_guide_developer.pdf). It's a bit outdated, but it's new enough.